# How can I get NuGet to ignore config transform values when they already exist?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

I have a class library package that needs to merge the following to the existing web/app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="MyCompany.MyLibrary" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <applicationSettings>
    <MyCompany.MyLibrary.Settings>
      <setting name="Environment" serializeAs="String">
        <value></value>
      </setting>
    </MyCompany.MyLibrary.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

I did this using .transform files and it installs fine.

The user (using NuGet 2.8.3 and VS 2012) is able to easily edit the value in "Environment" to properly configure the library.

However, when I release the next version, the user runs into a problem when they use NuGet to update their solution.

The update clears out their existing "Environment" value in the user's config files.

I tried using an .install.xdt file and do:

```
<setting name="Environment" serializeAs="String" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
```

That didn't work either.  Is there a way to tell NuGet to ignore the value under "Environment" if it's already there so it doesn't clear out existing values?

I don't want to apply that ignore logic to all of **MyCompany.MyLibrary.Settings** in case a future update adds or removes a new setting.